# Cloning subclasses of class into class

Tags: jquery, clone, children

I have following html markup.

```
<div class="master">
  <div class="item master-line"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item master-line"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

I need to clone the items children/sub of the master-line into the master-line class.

What I have tried, but does not work. And I am not sure it might be the best method:

```
$.each($('.item'), function(index, value){
        if($(value).hasClass('master-line')){    
         console.log($(value).next().find('.component_table_item'));
        }
    });
```

Unfortunately it is not possible to change the html markup (which would be preferable).

The end markup should look something like this:

```
<div class="master">
  <div class="item master-line">
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item master-line">
   <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tLhqkjoh/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
$.each($('.item.master-line'), function(index, value) {
  $(this).nextUntil(".master-line").appendTo($(this));
});
```

**demo**

```js
$.each($('.item.master-line'), function(index, value) {
  $(this).nextUntil(".master-line").appendTo($(this));
});

console.log($(".master").html().trim());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="master">
  <div class="item master-line"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item master-line"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tusinde tak. Koden virkede perfekt :-)

Comment: @simon No problem, happy to help